# overflow hidden needed in container makes appear scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, containers

I'm having a bit of trouble with overflow: hidden to give height to a container....

So.... if you see here: https://jsfiddle.net/8xxcm7vw/1/

html:

```
 <body>
    <div class="wrapperOrg">
      <div class="alignedLeft col-md-19 col-sm-20 col-xs-24">
        <nav id="topNavigation" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">  
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">      
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href=""><span>Manufracturer<span> </span>Approved</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href=""><span>Customer 1st<span> </span>We'll visit you</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href=""><span>Excess<span> </span>SAFE</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href=""><span>Friendly Form- <span> </span>Free Help</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href=""><span>FREE-<span> </span>Accident Management</span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>     
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div><div id="socialNavigation" class="alignedRight col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-18">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">          
          <li>
            <a href="#facebook">
              <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>  
            <a href="#googleplus">
              <i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#twitter">
              <i class="icon icon-youtube"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapperWh">
      <div class="alignedLeft static-top col-md-19 col-sm-20 col-xs-24">
        <nav id="mainNavigation" class="navbar navbar-default" navbar-static-top>
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="alignedLeft col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="navbar-brand ">
                <img src="images/advance_logo.png" alt=""/>
              </div>  
            </div>
                </div><div class="alignedRight col-md-17 col-sm-17col-xs-17">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">      
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                  <a href="">Accident<br>Management</a>
                  <div class="subMainNavigation">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-sx-5">
                      <img src="images/kitemark.png" alt=""/>
                      <p>There are many variations of passages. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-sx-9">
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="">Download App</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">Accident Helpline</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-10"></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href="">Approved<br>Manufacturers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">Our<br>Services</a>
                  <div class="subMainNavigation">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-sx-5">
                        <img src="images/kitemark.png" alt=""/>
                        <p>There are many variations of passages. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-sx-9">
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="">Structural Aluminium Repairs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Free Manufacturer paint/body inspection</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-10"></div> 
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href="">About<br>Advance</a>
                  <div class="subMainNavigation">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-sx-5">
                        <img src="images/kitemark.png" alt=""/>
                        <p>There are many variations of passages. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-sx-9">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Commitment to Quality</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Pride and Joy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Meet the team</a></li>
                      </ul>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sx-10"></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href="">Contact<br>Us</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div><div id="callNavigation" class="alignedRight col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-18">
        <a href="phone:">
          <i class="icon icon-phone"></i>
          <p>
            <span>Helpline</span>
            <span>01246 858500</span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div> 
       <div id="displaySubmenu" class="col-md-24 col-sm-24 col-xs-24"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapperMain">
      <div id="mainContent" class="col-md-24 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
      <div id="owl-main" class="owl-carousel">
          <div>
            <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/9f5c5mgi3/slider1.jpg" alt=""  class="img-responsive"/>          
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="floatingText">
              <h3>Advance Accident <span>MANAGEMENT</span></h3>
              <span>'We'll take the stress away'</span>
              <ul>
                 <li></i>Available all day, every day</li>
                 <li>Free replacement vehicle</li>
                 <li>Free Recovery, delivery a Collection, we'll come to you</li>
                 <li>We'll liase with your insurance company</li>
                 <li>Friendly, form-free help</li>
              </ul>
              <a href="#" class="orangeButton downloadApp"><p>DOWNLOAD</p><span>FREE APP</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div> <!-- ends wrapperMain--> 
  </body>
```

css:

```
.navbar-collapse{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

    .navbar-nav {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
        /*displaying inline block makes a little margin*/
        margin-top: 0.1%;
        margin-bottom: 0.1%;
    }
    .navbar-default {
        border:none;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius:0;
        box-shadow:none;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        padding:0;
    }

    /*vertical alignment*/
    .alignedLeft,
    .alignedRight{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
        float:none;
    }
    /**Top Navigation**/
    .wrapperOrg {
         background: #f9540a;
    }

    #topNavigation {
       background: #f9540a;
       font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
       font-weight:700;
       font-size:1.2em;
    }
    #topNavigation li {
        border-right:2px solid #d93700;
        box-shadow: 1.5px -0.5px 0px -0.5px rgba(255, 255, 250, 0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1.5px -0.5px 0px -0.5px rgba(255, 255, 250, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 1.5px -0.5px 0px -0.5px rgba(255, 255, 250, 0.5); 
    }
    #topNavigation li a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 3%;
    }
    #topNavigation .navbar-nav li a:hover {
        color: #808080;
    }
    #topNavigation li a span {
        display:block;
    }
    /*for better responsive*/
    #topNavigation li:first-child {
        width:21%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(2){
        width:19%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(3){
        width:13%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(4){
        width:20%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:last-child {
        width:27%;
        border:none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
    }

    /**Social Navigation**/
    #socialNavigation li {
        padding:0 1%;
    }
    #socialNavigation li a {
         color: #808080;
         text-decoration:none;   
         padding:0;
    }
    #socialNavigation li a:hover {
         color: #808080;
         text-decoration:none;   
         padding:0;
         background: none;
    }
    #socialNavigation li a i{
        font-size:3.5em;
        line-height: 1.2;
        color: #808080;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 2px #808080 inset;
    }

    /**Main Navigation**/
    .wrapperWh {
         background: #ffffff;
         /*relative to displayMenu*/
         position:relative;
         box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)
    }
    #mainNavigation {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:1.2em;
        /* relative to the fullSubMainNav*/
        position:relative;
    }
    #mainNavigation .navbar-brand {
        height: auto; 
        padding:0;
    }
    #mainNavigation ul li {
        border-right:2px solid red;
        padding:0 2%;
    }
    #mainNavigation ul li a {
      color:black;
      padding:0;
    }
    /*for better responsive*/
    #mainNavigation li:first-child {
        width:12%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(2){
        width:20%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(3){
        width:22%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(4),
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(5){
        width:15%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:last-child {
        width:16%;
        border:none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
    }

    /*full subnavigation for mainNavigation*/
    #fullSubMainNav {
        width:100%;
        /* absolute to mainNavigation*/
        border:1px solid blue;
        height:50px;
    }
    /*subnavigation for mainNavigation on hover*/
    .activeNav {
        display:block;
    }
    .subMainNavigation {
        display:none;
    }
    /*we are styling the subMainNavigation*/
    #displaySubmenu ul{
      font-family: "Droid Sans",sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 1.2em; 
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li{
     list-style:none;
     border-bottom:2px solid #d8d8d8;
     padding: 3% 0;
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li:last-child{
     list-style:none;
     border-bottom:none;
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li:before{
        content:"\25CF";
        color:#f9540a;
        padding-right:3%;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li a{
        color:#000;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #displaySubmenu { 
        background: #ffffff;
        /* absolute to #wrapperWh */
        position:absolute;
        top:100%;
        height:auto;
        z-index:1;
    }


    /* Call Navigation */
    #callNavigation a{
        color:black;
    }
    #callNavigation a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #callNavigation a p:last-child {
        font-weight:bold; 
    }
    #callNavigation p {
        display:inline;
    }
    #callNavigation p span{
        display:block;
    }
    #callNavigation p span:last-child{
        font-size:2em;
    }
    #callNavigation a i {
        color:#f9540a;
        font-size:3em;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float:left;
        padding-right: 2%;
    }
    /* main content */
        .curtainBackground { 
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
    }
    .wrapperMain {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #mainContent {
        height:auto;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: grey;
        z-index:-1; 
        /*relative for floatingText*/
        position:relative;
        font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:1.2em;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    }
    .floatingText {
        /* absolute for #owl-main*/
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:2%;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        color:#000;
    }
    .floatingText h3 {
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 3.5em;
    }
    .floatingText h3 span {
        color:#f9540a;
    }
    .floatingText ul {
        list-style:none;
        font-family:'icomoon';
        padding:0;

    }
    .floatingText ul li {
        height: 35px;
    }
    .floatingText ul li:before{
        content: "\e803";
        padding-right: 2%; 
        color:#f9540a;
        font-size:2em;
    }
    a.orangeButton {
        background-color:#f9540a;
        color: #FFF;
        padding:10px 50px;
        -webkit-border-radius:40px;
        -moz-border-radius:40px;
        border-radius:40px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5b5b5b;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5b5b5b;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5b5b5b;
        display: inline-block;

    }
    a.orangeButton:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .downloadApp {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
    .downloadApp p {
        font-size:26px;
        margin:0;
    }
    #owl-main > div {
       max-height: 950px; 
    }
    #owl-main > div img {
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 100%;  
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?rdonbp');
        src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?rdonbp#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?rdonbp') format('truetype'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?rdonbp') format('woff'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?rdonbp#icomoon') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;

        /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    [data-icon]:before {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        content: attr(data-icon);
        speak: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
    .icon-approved:before {
        content: "\e800";
    }
    .icon-facebook:before {
        content: "\e801";
    }
    .icon-phone:before {
        content: "\e802";
    }
    .icon-tick:before {
        content: "\e803";
    }
    .icon-twitter:before {
        content: "\e804";
    }
    .icon-youtube:before {
        content: "\e805";
    }



    /* Large devices Bootstrap(large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media screen and (max-width:1200px) { }

    /* Medium devices Bootstrap(desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media screen and (max-width:992px) {
      #topNavigation.navbar-default {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        #topNavigation ul {
        padding:0;
    }
        #socialNavigation li a i{
        font-size: 2.8em;
    }
    }
    /* Small devices Bootstrap(tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media screen and (max-width:768px) {  

    .navbar-nav{
            margin:0;
        }
          #topNavigation {
            width:100% !important;
            border:none;
            box-shadow: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            font-weight: 400;
    }
    #topNavigation ul {
        padding:0;
    }
    #topNavigation li {
        padding:1%;
    }
    /*for better responsive*/
    #topNavigation li:first-child,
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(2),
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(3),
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(4),
    #topNavigation li:last-child {
        width:100%;
        border:none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;   
        padding: 1% 2%;
    }
    #topNavigation li a {
        padding:1%;
    }
    #topNavigation li a span {
        display:inline;
    }
    #socialNavigation {
       position: absolute;
       left: 3%;
       top:0%;
    }
    #socialNavigation li {
        float:left;
        display:inline;
    }
    #socialNavigation li a i{
        font-size: 2.8em;
    }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:332px) { 
      #topNavigation li a {
        padding:2%;
    }
    }
```

I am using overflow:hidden on .wrapperMain, as otherwise it doesn't have height and consequently I can't apply the.curtainBackground. But because of this overflow, the orange button becomes not clickable!!!

I have tried several things.... clearing the container....overflow-x overflow-y, z-index high for the button... but nothing works.

You see, if instead I try to use overflow:auto, It makes appear an horizontal scrollbar, which is wrong too.

So the best approarch it's the one there is at the moment, but the button is not clickable. Any suggestion about how to solve this problem?

Thank you!!

Comment: You need to click orange button or not?.

Comment: yes yes, it is what I can not make it work! So I need the orange button working but also the horizontal scrollbar can not appear

Answer (score 0):

Update this css and run in your local. Updated link https://jsfiddle.net/8xxcm7vw/2/

```
    /*unwanted default Bootstrap*/
    .navbar-collapse{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
        /*displaying inline block makes a little margin*/
        margin-top: 0.1%;
        margin-bottom: 0.1%;
    }
    .navbar-default {
        border:none;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius:0;
        box-shadow:none;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        padding:0;
    }

    /*vertical alignment*/
    .alignedLeft,
    .alignedRight{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
        float:none;
    }
    /**Top Navigation**/
    .wrapperOrg {
        background: #f9540a none repeat scroll 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #topNavigation {
        background: #f9540a;
        font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:1.2em;
    }
    #topNavigation li {
        border-right:2px solid #d93700;
        box-shadow: 1.5px -0.5px 0px -0.5px rgba(255, 255, 250, 0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1.5px -0.5px 0px -0.5px rgba(255, 255, 250, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1.5px -0.5px 0px -0.5px rgba(255, 255, 250, 0.5);
    }
    #topNavigation li a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 3%;
    }
    #topNavigation .navbar-nav li a:hover {
        color: #808080;
    }
    #topNavigation li a span {
        display:block;
    }
    /*for better responsive*/
    #topNavigation li:first-child {
        width:21%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(2){
        width:19%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(3){
        width:13%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:nth-child(4){
        width:20%;
    }
    #topNavigation li:last-child {
        width:27%;
        border:none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
    }

    /**Social Navigation**/
    #socialNavigation li {
        padding:0 1%;
    }
    #socialNavigation li a {
        color: #808080;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:0;
    }
    #socialNavigation li a:hover {
        color: #808080;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:0;
        background: none;
    }
    #socialNavigation li a i{
        font-size:3.5em;
        line-height: 1.2;
        color: #808080;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 2px #808080 inset;
    }

    /**Main Navigation**/
    .wrapperWh {
        background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    #mainNavigation {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:1.2em;
        /* relative to the fullSubMainNav*/
        position:relative;
    }
    #mainNavigation .navbar-brand {
        height: auto;
        padding:0;
    }
    #mainNavigation ul li {
        border-right:2px solid red;
        padding:0 2%;
    }
    #mainNavigation ul li a {
        color:black;
        padding:0;
    }
    /*for better responsive*/
    #mainNavigation li:first-child {
        width:12%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(2){
        width:20%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(3){
        width:22%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(4),
    #mainNavigation li:nth-child(5){
        width:15%;
    }
    #mainNavigation li:last-child {
        width:16%;
        border:none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
    }

    /*full subnavigation for mainNavigation*/
    #fullSubMainNav {
        width:100%;
        /* absolute to mainNavigation*/
        border:1px solid blue;
        height:50px;
    }
    /*subnavigation for mainNavigation on hover*/
    .activeNav {
        display:block;
    }
    .subMainNavigation {
        display:none;
    }
    /*we are styling the subMainNavigation*/
    #displaySubmenu ul{
        font-family: "Droid Sans",sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li{
        list-style:none;
        border-bottom:2px solid #d8d8d8;
        padding: 3% 0;
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li:last-child{
        list-style:none;
        border-bottom:none;
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li:before{
        content:"\25CF";
        color:#f9540a;
        padding-right:3%;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #displaySubmenu ul li a{
        color:#000;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #displaySubmenu {
        background: #ffffff;
        /* absolute to #wrapperWh */
        position:absolute;
        top:100%;
        height:auto;
        z-index:1;
    }


    /* Call Navigation */
    #callNavigation a{
        color:black;
    }
    #callNavigation a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #callNavigation a p:last-child {
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    #callNavigation p {
        display:inline;
    }
    #callNavigation p span{
        display:block;
    }
    #callNavigation p span:last-child{
        font-size:2em;
    }
    #callNavigation a i {
        color:#f9540a;
        font-size:3em;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float:left;
        padding-right: 2%;
    }
    /* main content */
    .curtainBackground {
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }
    .wrapperMain {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #mainContent {
        background-color: grey;
        font-family: "Oswald",sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    .floatingText {
        /* absolute for #owl-main*/
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:2%;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        color:#000;
    }
    .floatingText h3 {
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 3.5em;
    }
    .floatingText h3 span {
        color:#f9540a;
    }
    .floatingText ul {
        list-style:none;
        font-family:'icomoon';
        padding:0;

    }
    .floatingText ul li {
        height: 35px;
    }
    .floatingText ul li:before{
        content: "\e803";
        padding-right: 2%;
        color:#f9540a;
        font-size:2em;
    }
    a.orangeButton {
        background-color:#f9540a;
        color: #FFF;
        padding:10px 50px;
        -webkit-border-radius:40px;
        -moz-border-radius:40px;
        border-radius:40px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5b5b5b;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5b5b5b;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5b5b5b;
        display: inline-block;

    }
    a.orangeButton:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .downloadApp {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
    .downloadApp p {
        font-size:26px;
        margin:0;
    }
    #owl-main > div {
        max-height: 950px;
    }
    #owl-main > div img {
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?rdonbp');
        src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?rdonbp#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?rdonbp') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?rdonbp') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?rdonbp#icomoon') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;

        /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    [data-icon]:before {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        content: attr(data-icon);
        speak: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
    .icon-approved:before {
        content: "\e800";
    }
    .icon-facebook:before {
        content: "\e801";
    }
    .icon-phone:before {
        content: "\e802";
    }
    .icon-tick:before {
        content: "\e803";
    }
    .icon-twitter:before {
        content: "\e804";
    }
    .icon-youtube:before {
        content: "\e805";
    }



    /* Large devices Bootstrap(large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media screen and (max-width:1200px) { }

    /* Medium devices Bootstrap(desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media screen and (max-width:992px) {
        #topNavigation.navbar-default {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        #topNavigation ul {
            padding:0;
        }
        #socialNavigation li a i{
            font-size: 2.8em;
        }
    }
    /* Small devices Bootstrap(tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media screen and (max-width:768px) {

        .navbar-nav{
            margin:0;
        }
        #topNavigation {
            width:100% !important;
            border:none;
            box-shadow: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        #topNavigation ul {
            padding:0;
        }
        #topNavigation li {
            padding:1%;
        }
        /*for better responsive*/
        #topNavigation li:first-child,
        #topNavigation li:nth-child(2),
        #topNavigation li:nth-child(3),
        #topNavigation li:nth-child(4),
        #topNavigation li:last-child {
            width:100%;
            border:none;
            box-shadow: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            padding: 1% 2%;
        }
        #topNavigation li a {
            padding:1%;
        }
        #topNavigation li a span {
            display:inline;
        }
        #socialNavigation {
            position: absolute;
            left: 3%;
            top:0%;
        }
        #socialNavigation li {
            float:left;
            display:inline;
        }
        #socialNavigation li a i{
            font-size: 2.8em;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:332px) {
        #topNavigation li a {
            padding:2%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: nope, with this way it doesn't add the curtainBackground because the wrapperMain does not have height....